# Foods that increase Melatonin (induce sleep)

Tags: sleep

I am trying to regulate my sleep but I don't like to drink pills or supplements. I was wondering if there are certain foods that help induce sleep?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=melatonin+foods

Comment: @RyanMiller do you do that to every single question? You see you just can't Google everything, that's why this site exists. Who do you trust, real advice or MFA sites?

Comment: MFA?  And, yes, that's how I got my 1300+ reputation - by not adding any value to any answer I've ever given.

Comment: you can google whatever you want, at least its a start.

Comment: @RyanMiller http://lmgtfy.com/?q=mfa+sites

Comment: Touche - nice retort

Comment: Changes to the sites scope of the site made this question off topic, as it is a nutrition question, have a look at the [FAQ].

Comment: Actually exercise has some effect on Tryptophan absorption.
(A bit the same effect as carbs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see here... melatonin is synthesized like this:

Tryptophan (Trp) --> 5-HTP --> Serotonin (5-HT) --> N-Acetylserotonin (NAS) --> Melatonin

As a result, any food which contains tryptophan is a good candidate.

**[Foods containing Trp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tryptophan#Dietary_sources):** Egg, Spirulina and Cod are good sources of tryptophan.

As it happens, [5-HTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5-Hydroxytryptophan) is also a good candidate, since you can buy it as a dietary supplement. Keep in mind though that whether you're boosting Trp or 5-HTP, you're facing a lot of rate-limiting enzymes so there's no telling how strong the effect is really going to be.

Of course you can just take melatonin directly, since it's available as a dietary supplement. If you need anything more powerful than that, go seek your doctor.

Comment: Turkey is a source of tryptophan

Comment: *Despite popular belief that turkey has a particularly high amount of tryptophan, the amount of tryptophan in turkey is typical of most poultry.* (Source: Wikipedia)